# Timelike paths in Reissner–Nordström black holes

Tags: general-relativity

Suppose we study Schwarzschild solution . If we are outside the event horizon then we follow a timelike path. And then our time t is forced to increase.

After surpassing the event horizon we are forced to go to decreasing r becuase now r is timelike.

Now take the charged solution. First we pass the outer horizon going to decreasing r(forced) then if we reach the inner horizon and the direction of decreasing r is stopped. Then we take the inverse rout and this time between the two horizon r is forced to increase?

We t in the first example is forced to increase, then in the second one r to decrease and the third one one time to decrease and the other to increase?